# why cant i get my page to append text and appear on my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

```
let mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode = document.createTextNode("hi");
myParagraph.append(myTextNode);
mainDiv.append(myParagraph);
let max = 25;
let oneToTwentyFive = [];
function oneHigh() {
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) oneToTwentyFive.push(i);
  console.log(oneToTwentyFive);
}
return oneHigh();
```

there is there javaScript

here is the HTML im working on

```
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>DOM MANIPULATION</h1>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="katas3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

im trying to make a function that send 1-25 numbers to my HTML page i got the function to console.log the proper numbers in a array but im just so confused i created a .append to try to just get ANYTHING on the HTML page but northings working :( can anyone please help?

Comment: `return` is outside the function.

Comment: dice is like a saying like "darn no dice"

Comment: If you have started learning since recently, just try to understand what you are trying to achieve (expected behaviour) from the current situation. Break your problem  "display a range of numbers inside an element in the page" down into smaller chunks. Do you have the element in the page? Good...Why do not you **test** that by introducing a `console.log` on line 7 so that the element if appended properly can be console logged? At the beginning, and this is just an quick tip, use `console.log` everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append content to html tag by using `append` in the `for` loop as shown below

```js
let mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode = document.createTextNode("hi");
myParagraph.append(myTextNode);
mainDiv.append(myParagraph);
let max = 25;
let oneToTwentyFive = [];
function oneHigh() {
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) mainDiv.append(i+' ');
}
oneHigh();
```

```html
<h1>DOM MANIPULATION</h1>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: do you want the output to be in this format? like `hi123456...` or any other?

Comment: dinesh is there a way i can message you for some advice?

Comment: @brianfuit1 There is no message system in SO. You can comment here or in my answer below regarding any query you have. I will be happy to answer and help you out!

Answer (score 2):

Use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to show the number from `1` to `25` and also save those number to an your array `oneToTwentyFive`

**Live Demo:**

```js
let mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode = document.createTextNode("hi");

myParagraph.appendChild(myTextNode);
mainDiv.appendChild(myParagraph);

let max = 25;
let oneToTwentyFive = [];

function oneHigh() {
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    mainDiv.innerHTML += i //show number
    oneToTwentyFive.push(i); //push data
  }
}
oneHigh();

//console.log(oneToTwentyFive)
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>DOM MANIPULATION</h1>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: hey Always Helping what is the difference between .appendChild and just .append?

Comment: `append()` allows you to also append `DOMString` objects, whereas `appendChild()` only accepts Node objects. To simply => Its depends on the context you are working with. I will prefer using `appendChild` in your case since you are appending some data to your parent Class which is `main` div. append will become the sibling of `main` and not a `child`